# Insercion de datos Foxpro en Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro, foxpro

Que tal espero se encuentren bien, tengo la siguiente duda, soy primerizo en esto de FoxPro, no entiendo casi nada, lo que pasa es que tengo que mudar tablas de FoxPro a Sql server, pero esto debe ser constante ya que el ERP de la empresa esta con esta tecnología y aun lo utilizan.

Logre llevarme una tabla completa (con pocos registros y pocas columnas) a SQL, mi problema esta en que quiero hacerlo con tablas mucho mas grandes pero por alguna razón me manda un error de **Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword**, por lo que he leído se debe a las tantas columnas que tiene. Intente concatenar.

```
USE c:\winmagi\data\fcstmod.dbf ALIAS fcstmod
SQLEXEC(lnHandle,"TRUNCATE TABLE FCSTMOD")
SCAN ALL
  lnResult = SQLEXEC(lnHandle, "INSERT INTO dbo.FCSTMOD"+;
  "VALUES (?DEFAULT,?DESC,?MODEL,?PCT1,?PCT10,?PCT11,?PCT12,?PCT2,?PCT3,?PCT4,?PCT5,?PCT6,?PCT7,?PCT8,?PCT9)")
  IF lnResult < 0

  ENDIF
ENDSCAN
```

pero de esta forma ya no funciona mi inserción, no me manda error pero no inserta nada.

**Este mismo código lo hice pero sin concatenar, es decir todo en una sola linea, de esta forma todo bien.**

Me gustaría saber si alguno ha pasado por esto y como lo ha solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Te estás enfrentando a un problema muy complicado por la falta de documentación en linea y usuarios activos de FoxPro. Tal vez, sería más eficiente ver otras opciones como:

- La posibilidad de generar archivos csv con las tablas y esos archivos importarlos a SQL Server mediante `BULK INSERT`, bcp o SSIS.

```
    USE some.dbf

    COPY TO some.csv TYPE CSV
```

- Instalar el [OLE DB Provider para Visual FoxPro](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) e importar el DBF mediante SSIS y un origen OLEDB.
- Instalar el OLE DB Provider y usarlo para crear un linked server en tu instancia de SQL Server para importar los datos con T-SQL puro.

*Con información tomada, traducida y resumida de [aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e68b095-83f5-40d4-a764-d1d1dd8ff140/convert-foxpro-table-to-quotcsvquot-file?forum=visualfoxprogeneral)*

Comment: De hecho esa era mi idea, poder hacerlo con archivos de forma mas sencilla, el problema esta en que como sera mudar las tablas prácticamente a diario porque el ERP se utiliza, no seria del todo conveniente usar los archivos, ademas de que mi superior lo requiere de esta manera, igual echare un vistazo y tratare de convencerlo a que se use de esta forma, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Las 3 opciones que incluí se pueden automatizar sin ningún problema. Los archivos se pueden destruir después de validar que la importación se realizó con éxito.